# A clever way to create (or not create them) folders with setup.py and Python?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am building a small command line software (let's say it's called *Stanley*) and packaging it with the [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#package-data). Basically my projet looks like this :

```
Stanley / __init__.py
        / foo.py
        / bar.py
        / datafiles / preference_file_1.metadata
                    / ...
                    / preference_file_n.metadata         
LICENSE
MANIFEST.in
README.md
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

*Stanley* needs to create some preference files in the folder datafiles but cannot import existing preference files (eg. using the `data_files` argument from `setuptools.setup()`) because they will contain information given by the users after the installation. Moreover I cannot create empty files in advance because I cannot tell in advance how many of those files will be created.

I need this folder to be created once, at the installation of *Stanley*. Any file created by *Stanley* in this folder must remain intact at each update. That is, when a user will run `$ pip3 install stanley --upgrade`, all the preferences contained in the folder datafiles will be preserved. So my questions are :

1) How to create the directory datafiles using the setuptools?
2) How to make sure that the files created by my software in datafiles will not be changed and will still be accessible in datafiles after a re-installation or an update?

Note that it is the first time that I program a "real" software including coding, testing, packaging, distributing (even though PyPi and Python make a lot of work for me), etc. Therefore I am not aware of many good practices, and if you tell me that my present way of managing user preferences is not the right one, I would be glad to change it in order to suit higher standards. Also if my problem is not clear, I am here to make you understand it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what your use-case for these datafiles is, but they appear to be user preference files, in which case the correct thing to do is to store them in the user's home directory, away from your package's code.  Use [appdirs](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs) to determine the proper path that your application should be storing the files in.

> 1. How to create the directory datafiles using the setuptools?

Don't create them with setuptools; write your package so that it creates the files in the proper place when the files are needed.

> 2. How to make sure that the files created by my software in datafiles will not be changed and will still be accessible in datafiles after a re-installation or an update?

The file are stored outside your package's code, so they aren't affected by uninstallations or updates.

Comment: Well this seems exactly like the good practices that I am looking for. Thanks for that. However I still need the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Stanley` to be created. Is there a way to create it during the installation or should I just test if it exists in my modules and create it if necessary?
Also having the `datafiles` folder allowed me to have a folder for tests in `~/Documents/Projects/Stanley/datafiles/` and another for the version released by Pip. In your case I have no choice but to manually change  the folder in the modules when coding or when releasing. Is that right?

Comment: @8827: Tests if it exists and create it if necessary.